# ¿Por que mis correos enviados por smtp a hotmail llegan a spam?

Tags: email, smtp

Estoy enviando un correo electronico con Laravel utilizando la configuracion smtp de mi servidor.

El correo se envia y llega de forma correcta a Gmail, pero en Hotmail este llega a la bandeja de Spam.

Realize pruebas al correo utilizando https://www.mail-tester.com/ el cual me entrega un puntaje 10/10 pero aun asi hotmail envia los correos a la bandeja de Spam.

Investigando llegue a una respuesta que indicaba que quizas el problema estaba en el contenido del correo, pero lo intente enviar solo con la letra "a" como contenido pero de igual manera lo envia a Spam.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda :)

Comment: Probablemente tu dominio o IP estén en alguna lista negra. Puedes revisar en: https://mxtoolbox.com/

Comment: Lo revisé y no, todas las listas me aparecen en "OK", tienes alguna otra idea de lo que puede ocasionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias razones por la cual un email puede caer en spam, ya sea configuraciones de tu servidor de mail, o características propias de la composición y redacción del email.

Entre estas:

- Listas negras.
- Composición del cuerpo del mail.
- Firmas
- Autenticación
- etc

Hay sitios como este que pueden ayudarte a medir la calidad de tus emails:

https://www.mail-tester.com/

Haz una prueba y ve que podría estar fallando, ya configurar en tus servidor de mail o cuerpo del mismo.

Comment: Hola, si, como comente ya hice las pruebas en https://www.mail-tester.com/ obteniendo 10/10, también verifique si la ip y el dominio estaban en alguna lista negra en https://www.mxtoolbox.com y nada, no está en ninguna lista negra. También intente enviar el correo solamente añadiendo una letra "a" en su cuerpo pero aun así Hotmail sigue enviándolo a la bandeja de Spam. ¿Alguna otra idea de que podría ocasionarlo ? Cabe recalcar que el problema solo lo tengo con Hotmail ya que en Gmail los correos llegan correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te entiendo, me pasa lo mismo. Hasta el minuto, son los headers al parecer. Le agregué List-Unsusbscribe, pero todavía pasa a spam con hola como mensaje.

Si averiguo algo, escribo.

Hasta el minuto, para agregar la cabecera que te mencioné

```
    $this->from('xxx@xxx.cl', 'nombre a mostrar')
                        ->subject('Renovación '.$a->domain)
                        ->view('emails.hosting.primeraviso2')
                        ->with([
                            'domain'=> $a->domain,
                            'renew_fecha_esp' => $dia_sp." de ".$mes_sp." de ".$ano_sp,
                            'startyear' => date ("Y",strtotime($a->start_date)),
                            'price' => ("$". number_format ( $a->price , 0 , '' , '.' )),
                            'monto' => $a->price,
                            'plan' => $a->plan,
                            'diskused' => $a->diskused,
                            'disklimit' => $a->disklimit,
                        ]);
    
                        $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
                            $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
                                'List-Unsubscribe', 'link como mailto por ejemplo'
                            );
                        });
    
                        return $this;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).